# Can't submit WP 8.0 xap files to Windows Store

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-dev-center

I am trying to submit a Windows Phone 8.0 xap file to the store. It uploads, after the upload it says *"Analyzing package"*, then *"An unexpected error occurred. Please try again later. If the problem continues, contact support."*

I contacted Microsoft, they told me to clear the cache, history, etc. and try again. I emptied my browsers and restarted, but it didn't work. And I guess the problem is not really about the browsers, because they are able to upload the xap files but they don't get accepted by Microsoft's system.

I also tried an old xap file which was accepted by Microsoft before. I stil get the same error, so that's probably not about my packages.

Comment: You need to go back to MS about this.  That's a really general error message.  I would seriously doubt anybody here having a solution.

Comment: Maybe they're no longer accepting app submissions for WP8.0?

Comment: use interet explorer to submit xap from windows 8.1 os

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem after create fresh app using command line. And allocate that app name on app store. i guess there would be problem of Microsoft Server.